# Docker cant install any packages

Tags: docker

I just started with docker.

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get update 
RUN apt-get install  apache2  curl apache2 php5 libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mcrypt php5-mysql php5-curl vim
RUN apt-get install apache2-utils 
RUN apt-get clean 
EXPOSE 89
CMD [“apache2ctl”, “-D”, “FOREGROUND”]
```

Errors:

```
sudo docker build -t apache_image:1.0 --no-cache=true .
[sudo] password for pj: 
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/7 : FROM ubuntu
 ---> 3b418d7b466a
Step 2/7 : RUN apt-get update
 ---> Running in 27548bc06017
Ign:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Ign:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Ign:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Ign:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Ign:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Ign:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
Ign:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Ign:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Ign:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Ign:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists...
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Removing intermediate container 27548bc06017
 ---> 1ccdce33040e
Step 3/7 : RUN apt-get install  apache2  curl apache2 php5 libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mcrypt php5-mysql php5-curl vim
 ---> Running in 174722660b4f
Reading package lists...
E: Unable to locate package apache2
E: Unable to locate package curl
E: Unable to locate package apache2
E: Unable to locate package php5
E: Unable to locate package libapache2-mod-php5
E: Unable to locate package php5-mcrypt
E: Unable to locate package php5-mysql
E: Unable to locate package php5-curl
E: Unable to locate package vim
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install  apache2  curl apache2 php5 libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mcrypt php5-mysql php5-curl vim' returned a non-zero code: 100
pj@pj-virtual-machine:~/apache$
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why are there 2x `apache2`s  and one of them has weird spacing? Shouldn't include such basic "syntax" mistakes in questions, even though they don't matter. Anyways, looks like Docker has connection problems, try restarting it (`sudo service docker restart`) and system to start basic debugging.

Comment: Looks like your Docker network is not connected to Internet. Restart your host. If not possible, restart network then restart Docker daemon, and see if you can use any prebuilt image to open bash and ping through to any Internet host.

Answer (score 1):

```
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install ...
```

The problem is running these two commands in separate `RUN` invocations. Combine into one:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install ...
```

---

References: [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42981752/23118) that links to
https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#run which obviously have changed since it was linked, but the answer contains quotes.

Comment: Having separate RUN statements leads to large layers, but it cannot cause the problems OP has.